# Laravel Mailable Queuing not working

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

i am trying to queue my laravel mails. I am using redis for queue the mails.

When ever i am sending an email, the mail didn't go through by the `queue:listen` functions start adding errors to `laravel.log`

Here is my mailable code

```
use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $bdy=array();
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($bdy)
    {
        $this->content = $bdy;
        $from_name=$this->content['from_name'];
        $from_email=$this->content['from_email'];
        $subject=$this->content['subject'];
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from("$from_email")->subject("$subject")->view('emails.blank')->with(['content'=>$this->content]);
    }
```

And the mailcontroller code is here

```
  $content = str_replace("{name}", $lst->name, $content);

            $bdy=[
                'message'=>$content,
                'from_email'=>$send_from_email,
                'from_name'=>$send_from_name,
                'subject'=>$subject
            ];


         $today=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." +2 minutes"));
            Mail::to($lst)->later($today,new MailRoom1($bdy));
```

The Error i am getting in laravel.log file is

```
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/Mail/MailRoom1.php(34): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/html/a...', 34, Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\Mail\MailRoom1->build()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(531): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php(116): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/SendQueuedMailable.php(52): Illuminate\Mail\Mailable->send(Object(Illuminate\Mail\Mailer))
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable->handle(Object(Illuminate\Mail\Mailer))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(531): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(114): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable))
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable))
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(42): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable), false)
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(69): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Array)
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(291): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(258): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(110): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), 'redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(100): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('redis', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(83): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('redis', 'default')
#24 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(531): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(182): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(262): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(167): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(826): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(190): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(123): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#36 /var/www/html/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#37 {main}  
[2017-05-18 18:25:00] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined variable: from_email in /var/www/html/app/Mail/MailRoom1.php:34
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to make the things complicated, make the class like this:

```
public $content;

public function __construct( $bdy ) {
    $this->content = $bdy;
}

public function build() {
    return $this->from($this->content['from_email'])
                ->subject($this->content['subject'])
                ->view('emails.blank')
                ->with(['content'=>$this->content]);
}
```

That's it.

**Note:** You don't need to add the `->with(['content'=>$this->content])` because your public variable `$this->content` is already available on your template `'emails.blank'` with the variable `$content`. Take a look on [mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#view-data)

Answer (score 1):

$from_email will only be available in your constructor, you want to set it as an attribute of the class so you can access it else where

```
protected $from_name;

protected $from_email;

protected $subject;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($bdy)
{
    $this->content = $bdy;
    $this->from_name=$this->content['from_name'];
    $this->from_email=$this->content['from_email'];
    $this->subject=$this->content['subject'];
}

public function getFromEmail()
{
    return $this->from_email;
}

public function getFromName()
{
    return $this->from_name;
}

public function getSubject()
{
    return $this->subject;
}


/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from($this->getFromEmail())->subject($this->getSubject())->view('emails.blank')->with(['content'=>$this->content]);
}
```

Comment: Now i am getting $from_name, $from_email AND $subject must be public

Comment: change them to public rather than protected or create getters and setter functions

Comment: I've updated the answer to show getters and setters method

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Also any property declared as public can be accessed in your view.

```
public $content = array();

public $from = array();

public $subject;

function __construct($body)
{
    $this->content = $body['message'];

    $this->from = [
        'address' => $body['from_email'],
        'name' => $body['from_name']
    ];

    $this->subject = $body['subject'];
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->from($this->from)
        ->subject($this->subject)
        ->view('emails.blank')
        ->with(['content' => $this->content]);
}
```